# Why does my executorservice.submit returns null?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, executorservice, callable

I want to call several external APIs concurrently with multithreading in java spring, then I use it like this:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ServiceImpl");
    
    @Autowired
    SM sm;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Map getReturnsSeq(Map params) throws Exception {
        Map result1 = sm.callAPI1(params);
        Map result2 = sm.callAPI2(params);
        Map result3 = sm.callAPI3(params);
        Map result4 = sm.callAPI4(params);
        Map returnMap = new HashMap<>();
        List comb1and2 = new ArrayList();
        comb1and2.addAll((List) result1.get("data"));
        comb1and2.addAll((List) result2.get("list_data"));
        Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.get("date").compareTo(o1.get("date"));
        comb1and2.sort(mapComparator);
        returnMap.put("cmb12", comb1and2);
        returnMap.put("api_3", result3);
        returnMap.put("api_4", result4);
        return returnMap
    }
    
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Map getReturnsCon(Map params) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService e1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ExecutorService e2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ExecutorService e3 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ExecutorService e4 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Map returnMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Future<Map> result1 = e1.submit(new RecommendationAndHistory(params, 1));
            Future<Map> result2 = e2.submit(new RecommendationAndHistory(params, 2));
            Future<Map> result3 = e3.submit(new RecommendationAndHistory(params, 3));
            Future<Map> result4 = e4.submit(new RecommendationAndHistory(params, 4));
            
            List comb1and2 = new ArrayList();
            comb1and2.addAll(result1.get().get("data"));
            comb1and2.addAll(result2.get().get("list_data"));
            Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.get("date").compareTo(o1.get("date"));
            comb1and2.sort(mapComparator);
            returnMap.put("cmb12", comb1and2);
            returnMap.put("api_3", result3.get());
            returnMap.put("api_4", result4.get());
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            e1.shutdown();
            e2.shutdown();
            e3.shutdown();
            e4.shutdown();
        }
        return returnMap;
    }

    class RecommendationAndHistory implements Callable<Map> {
        private Map params;
        private int code;
        public RecommendationAndHistory(Map param, int cd) {
            this.params = param;
            this.code = cd;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Map call() throws Exception {
            if(code == 1) {
                return sm.callAPI1(params);
            } else if(code == 2) {
                return sm.callAPI2(params);
            } else if(code == 3) {
                return sm.callAPI3(params);
            } else if(code == 4) {
                return sm.callAPI4(params);
            }
            return null;
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is example of the `callAPI1`:

```
    @Override
    public function callAPI1(Map params) {
        ExternalAPI e = externalAPIDao.getExternalAPI("API_1");
        String url = e.getUrl() + "/get_history";
        RestMiddlewareCommunicator rest = new RestMiddlewareCommunicator();
        rest.setInputStream(true);
        rest.setOutputStream(true);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = this.get_resttemplate();
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
```

The `externalAPIDao.getExternalAPI(String name)` contains:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
ExternalAPI e = session.createQuery("from EAPI where name = :name").setParameter("name", name).uniqueResult();
return e;
```

I can run the `getReturnsSeq` normally everytime, but takes very very long time. However, I got null everytime I run `getReturnsCon`. So, what is actually wrong from my code above and how to resolve it?

#### Edit

---

The results of the executors were null because of the `HibernateException` that can't get the `currentSession` for the currently running thread. Therefore I come back to the sequential process although it takes a long time, since currently I can't find the way out of this.

I am still wondering about how can I overcome this long execution time with multithreading without getting such exception from Hibernate. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't look like the future object is null. Do you mean the result inside future is null? in that case, your `sm.callAPIx` could be returning null. Can you post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ArunGowda If I don't use the multithreading, it can return normally, but takes so long to obtain the results from those 4 functions

Comment: @ArunGowda Is this already enough to explain?

Comment: are you sure the future objects `result1,result2,result3..` are null? I can't replicate this.

Comment: Also, you don't need so many executors every time that method is called.. create a bean of it and inject it wherever needed.

Comment: So, do you mean that I just need to `ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` and use that `e` for `submit` for those 5 functions??

Comment: that's right. Why do you want to create  a new executor and destroy it after the method call.

Comment: What is “`getReturnsCon`”? Besides that, any of your problems may come from the `catch (Exception e){ logger.debug(e.getMessage()); }` An exception should be logged with at least *warning* level, further, you should not proceed after an exception, as your result map may be missing entries or even be entirely empty.

Comment: @Holger Edited. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: And I met HibernateException due to multithreading @Holger